# Catch Redirect URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect

Is there a way to detect the redirect url of your mvc page when a button is pressed so that you can display this url through javascript.

For example. A button is pressed that will redirect from localhost:1772/tasks to localhost:1772/tasks?actionname=StockReq.

Catch the localhost:1772/tasks?actionname=StockReq redirect url in var redirecturl and show an alert("redirecting to: " +  redirecturl).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a better way.
if you are aware of your rendered button, you may append a property (data-targeturl) where you will generate inside the full URL of your link/button, and by using a simple javascript code, you can capture the click event, read the property from the clicked link/button, and show it by your desired way.

also you may note that most fo the time you would end up with anchors when trying to render actionlinks (which is the MVC way to render a control that leads to another action/page inside your solution) so you can simply read the `href` property and do the same.

Comment: The situation is actually much more complex. I just provide a simple example so that no one would get lost in what it is I want to do

Comment: can you provide me with some example so I can help?

Comment: There is actually a control I use that redirects to a url through some javascript but I cannot find the javascript that does this. This is a kendo ui control. Now I'm trying to capture that redirected url so that i can use it.